How to find the internal temperature of a satellite assuming the satellite is just a box in space with no working subsystems?
I am working on a school project for a 3U Cubesat, specifically the thermal control subsystem. First, I would like to calculate the internal temperature of a "satellite" (assuming the "satellite" is just a box orbiting at 650 km with no working subsystems).
I was trying to use the equation $Q = σεA(T_1^4-T_2^4)$. We are assuming the power to be 40 W, the emissivity to be 0.75 based on the aluminum chosen, and the area can be calculated knowing it is a 3U CubeSat. Since we are at 650 km in altitude, I used this website (http://www.braeunig.us/space/atmos.htm) to get a temperature of 1,012 K. I used the "mean solar activity" temperature because the satellite will spend half of the day in sunlight and half of the day not in sunlight. I am not sure if this temperature is accurate, so I guess input on that would be useful as well.
Given this information, how do I go about finding the internal temperature?
I tried to use the above equation, but the internal temperature I got seemed far too high for a functioning 3U CubeSat. Can I use this equation or do I need another one, a different one, or more information? I am trying to keep this pretty basic and am not really worrying about other outside factors at this point in the project.

Are you sure you're going to be in daylight only half the day? It's probably actually more than that. Depending on your altitude, you might get significantly more sunlight than dark, though I imagine a cubesat is aiming for an extremely low orbit, so it might be close enough to 50% that the difference doesn't matter.

It looks like you're trying to use the Stefan-Boltzmann Law, but why have you introduced the $T_2$ (term which I take from your link that you've set at 700K?)  Would you mind showing some more of your work?

More generally, the way you are talking about this:  "use this equation," "Can I use this equation or do I need another one," etc:  it sounds like you don't understand what motivates the choice of one equation over another.  What do you actually understand about what you're trying to do and the work you've attempted?  What level of schooling is this project for?

I suggest you use this reference: https://www.academia.edu/934756/Thermal_Control_Handbook. Start at page 21 for an excellent introduction to thermal issues in low Earth orbit.

Simplest method:
use the Planetary equilibrium temperature equation:
$$T_{eq} = \left( \frac{I_0(1 - A_B)}{4 \sigma} \right)^{1/4}$$
where $A_B$ is a single value for the object's albedo at all wavelengths and $\sigma$ is the Stefan–Boltzmann constant, about 5.67×10-8 W/m2/K4. $I_0$ is the intensity of sunlight, which at 1 AU is about 1361 W/m2 (again, summed over all wavelengths).
Since for opaque surfaces, albedo = 1 - emissivity, $A_B$ = 0.25 which gives 259 K or -34° C
How does this deviate from reality?

Internal heat generation will make this hotter
Passing through Earth's shadow will make this colder
Most materials have very different emissivities at visible wavelengths (heating from the Sun) and thermal infrared wavelengths (radiative cooling) so you'd need to use a more complicated expression, which incorporates your $Q = σεA(T_1^4-T_2^4)$.
Shapes are complex, not spherical
Surfaces are a mixture of various materials

Spherical cow with two emissivities:
Let's start with a sphere of radius $r_0$. It has thermal infrared and visible light emissivities $e_{th}$ and $e_{vis}$. We'll include some near infrared in "visible" so that we can still use $I_0$ = 1361 W/m2 as a good approximation for the incoming heat flux.

$Q_{sun} = I_0 e_{vis} \pi r^2$ is the power absorbed from the Sun
$Q_{in} =$ constant is the heat generated internally
$Q_{rad} = \sigma e_{th} 4 \pi r^2 T^4 $ is the heat radiated.

We know that the object will increase in temperature until the radiated power equals the absorbed and internally generated powers:
$$Q_{rad} = Q_{sun} + Q_{in}$$
$$\sigma e_{th} 4 \pi r^2 T_{eq}^4 = I_0 e_{vis} \pi r^2 + Q_{in}$$
$$T_{eq}^4 = (I_0 e_{vis} \pi r^2 + Q_{in}) / (\sigma e_{th} 4 \pi r^2 )$$
$$T_{eq} = \left( \frac{I_0 e_{vis} \pi r^2 + Q_{in} }{\sigma e_{th} 4 \pi r^2 } \right)^{1/4}$$
If we assume an average visible light emissivity of 0.6 and thermal infrared emissivity of 0.8, a radius of 1 meter and an internal heat generation of 5 kW (let's say it's a 50 kW radar spy satellite with 90% efficiency and has no special heat dissipation panels) then the equilibrium temperature would be 339 K or 46° C.
If we go into Earth's shadow, that could drop to 13° C, depending on thermal inertia.
If we turn off the internal power dissipation, that expression becomes
$$T_{eq} = \left( \frac{I_0 e_{vis} \pi r^2}{\sigma e_{th} 4 \pi r^2 } \right)^{1/4} = \left( \frac{I_0 e_{vis}}{4 \sigma e_{th}} \right)^{1/4}$$
If we set $e_{vis} = 1 - A_B$ and assume the thermal emissivity is 1, it reduces to the Planetary equilibrium temperature approximation at the beginning.

For an approximation, you could use the planetary equilibrium temperature. From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetary_equilibrium_temperature

The planetary equilibrium temperature is a theoretical temperature
that a planet would be if it were in radiative equilibrium, typically
under the assumption that it radiates as a black body being heated
only by its parent star. In this model, the presence or absence of an
atmosphere (and therefore any greenhouse effect) is irrelevant, as the
equilibrium temperature is calculated purely from a balance with
incident stellar energy.

For such an oversimplification, this calculated quantity correlates remarkably well with empirical measurements.. From
http://astro.vaporia.com/start/equilibriumtemperature.html

The advantage of this fudge is you only have to know the distance from the sun and the satellite’s albedo. The proximity of the Earth gets ignored since it has been warmed to the same "planetary equilibrium temperature" as your satellite.
Very sloppy physics, but it will get you in the ballpark.

I don't think it's a good idea for a student doing a project about thermal control to assume that the satellite's temperature is going to be fixed at a certain value.  That would imply that no control is needed.
